# JavaFX ColumnConstraint minWidth being ignored, preWidth used, when resizing Window

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm I wrong to think that when resizing a window for a JavaFX-based application, the configured minimum size for a column width constraint should be used instead of the preferred size?

The program is pretty simple, from a book: *JavaFX 9 By Example*, with some minor changes to work in Eclipse with JavaFX 15.

First a picture showing the desired outcome. I've set the fxml ColumnConstraints *prefWidth* value to 50, which is the same as the *minWidth*.

[image: column constraint with desired behavior]

Now, the same application is launched with a single change: the *prefWidth* is set to 150 instead of 50. When making the horizontal window size smaller with the mouse, you can see that the application is not using the *minWidth* setting (minWidth was not changed). I didn't shrink the horizontal to its minimum, to make it more visually obvious that the contents are being clipped.

[image: column constraint unexpected behavior]

Following are the two additional classes in this project (am skipping displaying the module-info). But I don't think there is anything here that affects the gist of the question.

```
package com.jfxbe;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLContactFormX extends Application {
     
    /**                      
     * @param args the command line arguments                      
     */                      
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("FXMLContactForm ");

        Parent root = null;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ContactFormX.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 380, 150, Color.WHITE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMinWidth(200);
        stage.setMinHeight(150);

        stage.show();
    }
}

package com.jfxbe;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ContactFormXController {
       @FXML private TextField firstNameField;
       @FXML private TextField lastNameField;
       @FXML private Button saveButton;
       
       @FXML 
       protected void saveContactAction(ActionEvent event) {
           System.out.println("Saving the following information: ");
           System.out.println("First Name: " + firstNameField.getText());
           System.out.println(" Last Name: " + lastNameField.getText());
           }
}
```

Am I missing something in how column constraints work? Is there documentation that explains what is going on with the *minWidth* being ignored or not?

Comment: Just a quick guess: because you have `hgrow="ALWAYS"`, the column is forced to use at least its preferred width. Try setting it to `SOMETIMES`.

Comment: Seems to me like a good try, but "SOMETIMES" didn't change the outcome. Thanks for the suggestion, though.